# Biopython translation error: TypeError: 'generator' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, biopython

I have a problem in my code, which makes me frustrated.

```
#!usr/bin/python
import os,sys
import Bio
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord
from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC
fastaname = sys.argv[1]
in_put = open(fastaname,"rU")
out_put = open(fastaname[:-6] + "pro.fa","w")
m_record = SeqIO.parse(in_put, "fasta")
x = str(m_record)
start = x.find("ATG")
n = m_record[start:]
pro_records = (rec.translate(id = rec.id, to_stop = True) for rec in n)
SeqIO.write(pro_records, out_put, "fasta")
in_put.close()
out_put.close()
```

Running it with

```
$ python script test.fasta
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "translation.py", line 14, in <module>
n = m_record[start:]
TypeError: 'generator' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

and the test file `test.fasta`

```
>GRMZM5G800101_T01  
ATGATCTGGCATGTACAGAATTAG
```

Comment: I used what you mentioned. However, it's still the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the error message states, `m_record` is a generator.

If you want to use it like a list, which you're doing, you should create a list from it first.

```
m_record = list(SeqIO.parse(in_put, "fasta"))
```

Comment: Thank you. But when I ran this script, the result file was empty. Any suggestion?

Comment: @HailongYang Your error occurs when searching for the startindex. `m_record` is a list of `SeqRecord`. Using `str` to find the start of the subsequence yields in an index to big, so `n` is an empty; as well as `pro_records`. You need to find another approach of finding the subsequence you'd like to have.